Why ant addoninstall command is breaking Swagger/OCC?
We have recently encountered an issue with SAP Composable Storefront on our developers' localhost systems where after running the ant addoninstall command and then 'ant clean all', it is corrupting Swagger/OCC in base SAP Commerce.
When we first received reports of this problem, our developers were telling us that they could no longer log into Composable Storefront on their localhost systems. It took us a little while to trace the problem down to the steps that we have and to discover that Swagger/OCC is getting corrupted.
What we have been doing to quickly determine that Swagger/OCC is corrupt is navigating to the localhost Swagger url:
https://my.local:9002/rest/v2/swagger-ui/index.html
When Swagger/OCC has been corrupted, we are getting a 404 error message.
We are using SAP Commerce version 2211.16 and Composable Storefront version 2211.23, and we have encountered this issue on both Windows 10 and Windows 11 machines.
To reproduce the issue, we install base Commerce first:

Create new localhost SQL Server database using instructions from SAP's website.
Get a fresh copy of sapcc source code from repository
Unzip SAP Commerce 2211.16 zip file
Run first ant command from Windows Command prompt:

cd d:\hybris\hybris\bin\platform
setantenv.bat
ant clean all -Dinput.template=develop

Create custom folder
cd d:\hybris\hybris\bin
mkdir custom

Create symbolic links in powershell


d:
cd \hybris\hybris\bin\custom
New-Item -itemtype symboliclink -path D:\hybris\hybris\bin\custom -name my -value C:\GB_Dev\installsapcommercelocalhost_2211\sapcc\core-customize\my
New-Item -itemtype symboliclink -path D:\hybris\hybris\bin\custom -name mycommercewebservices -value C:\GB_Dev\installsapcommercelocalhost_2211\sapcc\core-customize\mycommercewebservices

Copy files to hybris\config folder

localextensions.xml
local.properties

Run first addoninstall command (this is not the one causing the problem) in windows command prompt

cd \hybris\hybris\bin\platform
ant addoninstall -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront=mystorefront -Daddonnames="b2bacceleratoraddon,commerceorgaddon,assistedservicestorefront,smarteditaddon,sapcoreaddon,b2bpunchoutaddon,myaddon,acceleratorwebservicesaddon,b2boccaddon,cmsoccaddon"

Initialize the new system in Windows Command prompt

cd d:\hybris\hybris\bin\platform
setantenv.bat
ant initialize

Start storefront

hybrisserver.bat

HAC update
Go into HAC and choose our initialdata extension to import

At this point, we are finished installing base SAP Commerce. After the HAC update has completed, we can successfully open the localhost Swagger console using the following URL:
https://my.local:9002/rest/v2/swagger-ui/index.html
Then we proceed onto installing Spartacus Mobile on localhost.

Stop the localhost server

Run second addoninstall command (this is the one we believe is causing the problem) in Windows Command Prompt


ant addoninstall -DaddonStorefront.ycommercewebservices=mycommercewebservices -Daddonnames="cmsoccaddon,b2boccaddon,acceleratorwebservicesaddon"

Build the platform

ant clean all

Start storefront

hybrisserver.bat
At this point, after the server finishes coming up, we encounter the issue where Swagger/OCC has been corrupted, and again we can confirm this by navigating to the localhost swagger url:
https://my.local:9002/rest/v2/swagger-ui/index.html
We get a 404 error when going to that url, and if we proceed to finish up the Composable Storefront installation, the Composable Storefront would not be able to reach the base SAP Commerce installation.
We've done some playing around with that second addoninstall command, and it appears to be the 'b2boccaddon' that is actually causing our problem.
We've been stuck for a while, and I'm hoping someone can point us in the correct direction of where to look for fixing this.

Did you check the console log of the hybris server? I assume that your context couldn't initialize properly during start.
